Livewire Requests Blocked by Azure Front Door WAF in Prevention Mode
Laravel Livewire application hosted on an Azure server. We have enabled Azure Front Door Web Application Firewall (WAF) in Prevention mode. However, we are encountering an issue where requests from Livewire are being blocked by the WAF. The error message returned is:
The request is blocked.
20240611T070599L-r15646b4954ffzb75tbdwwms5c00000005dg00000000abcd

Details:
Azure Setup: We have configured Azure Front Door WAF in prevention mode to enhance security.
Error Message: The specific error message received from the server indicates a request being blocked due to suspected suspicious activity.
Livewire Request Example:
Request: {"_token":"56B8efYCENB2X5t0u00C0DirE1myAllb34JGqjjy","components":[{"snapshot":"{\"data\":{\"showLoginInfo\":false,\"showOTPVerify\":true,\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"is_resend_otp\":null,\"generateOTP\":null,\"verify_otp_code\":\"\",\"device_token\":null,\"isEmailSubmitting\":false,\"passwordVisible\":false},\"memo\":{\"id\":\"X4eKX7VMoOT4SbU9B4Nv\",\"name\":\"auth.login\",\"path\":\"\\/\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"children\":[],\"scripts\":[],\"assets\":[],\"errors\":[],\"locale\":\"en\"},\"checksum\":\"3pk04241276cec0bc49097d0599e857856c58de6cf408112647199bf2a0fb9k3\"}","updates":{"verify_otp_code":"123456"},"calls":[{"path":"","method":"verifyOtp","params":[]}]}]}
According to the server team, the request is being flagged by the firewall rules as suspicious, specifically triggering a rule associated with SQL injection (sqli) patterns. The WAF log indicates the rule in question is related to the OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS), particularly regexp-942200.
Reference link: regexp-942200
Here are some details of the regular expressions causing the issue:
sqli rulerevision: disassembling sqli rules

    ,.*?[)\da-f\"'`][\"'`][\"'`].*?[\"'`]

RE2 compatibility for 942200 (#1461)
,.*?[)\da-f\"'`][\"'`](?:\r?\n)?\z

sqli rulerevision: disassembling sqli rules
,.*?[)\da-f\"'`][\"'`][^\"'`]+
\Wselect.+\W*?from
select\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
create\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
rename\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
truncate\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
load\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
alter\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
delete\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
update\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
insert\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(
desc\s*?\(\s*?space\s*?\(

Concerns:
Suspicious Activity: The Azure support team mentioned that the request was blocked due to suspicious activity, but we are not creating any manual requests. All requests are automatically generated by Livewire.
Firewall Rules: We understand that disabling rules one by one could help identify the issue, but this may pose security risks.
We identified that the requests are being blocked due to suspected SQL injection patterns.
The recommended solution to disable the rules one by one poses a security risk and is not a viable option.
Questions:
Livewire Request Structure: Is there anything in the structure of Livewire requests that might be flagged as suspicious by security systems such as Azure Front Door WAF?
Error Handling: Has anyone encountered similar issues, and if so, how were they resolved?
Could you provide any insights on why Livewire requests might be triggering these specific WAF rules?
Are there any known issues or configurations in Livewire that could lead to such false positives?
Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.

CRS dev-on-duty here. I can only respond from a WAF (CRS) perspective.
In fact, Azure uses the CRS in version 3.2. It's possible that so called false positives occur: legitimate traffic looks like suspicious activity, but is actually legitimate. If this happens, the CRS/WAF has to be tuned. To be able to tune the CRS, we need logs (I don't see any logs in your post, only changes to the rule 942200) to identify which argument triggered a specific rule. Then the tuning process is to remove a specific argument from a specific rule. I could help you with this process.
But as I said, this is only from WAF perspective and I don't know if your blocks are due to suspicious activity or if this is normal traffic from Livewire.
